# Vala - Gtk.Window.show_all() is not working after window closed?

Tags: window, gtk, hide, show, vala

I've created a Gtk.Window like this:

```cs
var window = Gtk.Window();

var label = Gtk.Label("here is a label");
window.add(label);
```

And toggling it with a button in this function:

```cs
private void toggle() {
    if (window.visible)
        window.hide();
    else
        window.show_all();
}
```

It is working fine, but if I close the window on its 'X' button, it doesn't show the items inside of it anymore. **It shows empty window.**

Why this is happening and how can I solve it? *(Is there a some kind of "not closing but hiding" solution overrides the window's 'X' button's function? Because it seems like when it closed, it is really deletes everything.)*

Thanks!

Comment: I've found that there is a property called `deletable` which removes close button. It partly solved my problem, but I just want to close a popup for example, not completely remove it.